# Enabling Disk Encryption with BitLocker Via Powershell On the Operating System Drive (C:\)

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I hope somebody here has run into the same issue as myself.

Oddities running my Powershell script to enable Bitlocker, appears to get to 95% sometimes however most times it fails.

OS - Windows 10 Professional 1809
GPO - Running Microsoft's best practices

I've been reading multiple forums and Windows best practices for setting Bitlocker via Powershell, none seem to have the specific answer

```
Enable-BitLocker -MountPoint "C:" -EncryptionMethod Aes256 -RecoveryKeyPath "Valid Path" -RecoveryKeyProtector

do 
{
    $Volume = Get-BitLockerVolume -MountPoint C:
    Write-Progress -Activity "Encrypting volume $($Volume.MountPoint)" -Status "Encryption Progress:" -PercentComplete $Volume.EncryptionPercentage
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}
until ($Volume.VolumeStatus -eq 'FullyEncrypted')

####################################################################
"Valid Path" refers to a valid UNC path with valid credentials.
```

The output seems to come back with:

```
#################################################################
Enable-BitLockerInternal : Value does not fall within the expected range.
At C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\BitLocker\BitLocker.psm1:3733 char:48
+ ... eInternal = Enable-BitLockerInternal -MountPoint $BitLockerVolumeInte ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Enable-BitLockerInternal
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this happens with self-encrypting drives using an encryption method below what is required by Group Policy.

My fix:

1. ```
   manage-bde -off C:
   ```
2. Delete the files in `C:\Windows\System32\Recovery`
3. Wait for it to decrypt
4. Re-run `enable-bitlocker`

Comment: I find this to be an interesting problem. Would you happen to know of a way to check to see a self-encrypting drive's current encryption method?